# Initialize a single row, multiple column array in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, initialization

I think this should be obvious, but this is a special case with no real answer that I have been able to find.
I wish to declare and initialize a (0,n) Array and have no idea what the proper syntax might be.
Something like:

```
Public Shared A(,) = {{,"One"},{,"Two"},{,"Three"}}
```

is the closest I have come, but that is not legal.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Out of interest, why would a regular one dimensional array, such as Public Shared A() = {"One","Two","Three"} not suffice?  Are you planning on redimming the array later?

Comment: `Dim myArray As String()() = {({""}), ({"one", "two", "three"})}` I think is what you want...I'm a little rusty on my arrays what with all the cool Lists and Dictionaries and Collections.  If not these guys might know:  [Arrays in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/wak0wfyt.aspx)

Comment: This is a tiny bit of a rather large Class Library which produces data that must be in an Excel friendly format. What that basically means is that everything must be returned/available as 2D arrays, even when only a 1D array or list or ... is the internal representation.
@Plutonix: Interesting thought, but, that produces a single dimension Array of Arrays.

Initializing a 1D array and then transforming it is what I am doing now, but it just offends my sense of what it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the below declaration will initialise an array of (0,n)

```
    Dim test(,) = {{"One", "Two", "Three"}}

    ' The below will print "Two"
    Debug.Print(test(0, 1))
```

Comment: That is IT!! I knew it had to be simple - but not obvious.

Comment: Hi @user12345 welcome to Stack Overflow.  If you ever get an answer that solves your question, please consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both yourself and the answerer. There is no obligation to do this.  I hope you enjoy using Stack Overflow.